# Why can't I run keytool.exe?

Tags: android, md5, api-key

I begin android programming and i can't find api key:(
I want to find apiKey for show map in my program.
I copy debug.keystore in andoid folder in C drive and when i clicked in keytool.exe in jdk folder, this closed fast and i cant read message in page. Why?
Should i do other works for find api Key? I read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey but i don't understand what is MD5! :(

Answer (score 1):

you need to run "keytool" from the command line, passing in one to many of the available parameters. it isn't a GUI-based application. try "keytool -h" to see the available parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`keytool` is a command line based program, and you can't run it as a GUI app. Try opening CMD and using:

```
keytool -list -alias <your_alias_name> -keystore <path_to_your_key.keystore>
```

You will then be asked for the passwords to the key and the alias. After entering those, you'll get an [MD5 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) as an output.